# Update list's values

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

I have the following setup:

```
1> rd(rec, {name, value}).
rec
2> L = [#rec{name = a, value = 1}, #rec{name = b, value = 2}, #rec{name = c, value = 3}].
[#rec{name = a,value = 1},
 #rec{name = b,value = 2},
 #rec{name = c,value = 3}]
3> M = [#rec{name = a, value = 111}, #rec{name = c, value = 333}].
[#rec{name = a,value = 111},#rec{name = c,value = 333}]
```

The elements in list `L` are unique based on their `name`. I also don't know the previous values of the elements in list `M`. What I am trying to do is to update list `L` with the values in list `M`, while keeping the elements of `L` that are not present in `M`. I did the following:

```
update_values([], _M, Acc) ->
    Acc;
update_attributes_from_fact([H|T], M, Acc) ->
    case [X#rec.value || X <- M, X#rec.name =:= H#rec.name] of
      [] ->
        update_values(T, M, [H|Acc]);
      [NewValue] ->
        update_values(T, M, [H#rec{value = NewValue}|Acc])
    end.
```

It does the job but I wonder if there is a simpler method that uses bifs.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I take it that you just want to update one field of the record not the whole record. Your example does this but you don't explicitly say this.

Comment: The `name` field remains the same, so there is no point in updating it. I could write `update_values(T, M, [#rec{name = H#rec.name, value = NewValue}|Acc])` but I believe the other way is clearer of my intentions.

Comment: I was more wondering if you wanted a solution for this specific record or for a more general case of a record with more fields than just a key and a value. If the 2nd case then what should happend with the other fields.

Comment: Please, do suggest a solution for a general record where the one of the fields needs to be updated and the rest to remain the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no existing function that does this for you, since you just want to update the value field rather than replacing the entire record in L (like lists:keyreplace() does). If both L and M can be long, I recommend that if you can, you change L from a list to a dict or gb_tree using #rec.name as key. Then you can loop over M, and for each element in M, look up the correct entry if there is one and write back the updated record. The loop can be written as a fold. Even if you convert the list L to a dict first and convert it back again after the loop, it will be more efficient than the L*M approach. But if M is always short and you don't want to keep L as a dict in the rest of the code, your current approach is good.

Comment: `lists:keyreplace` will do the job because the `name` field remains the same and I can simply override it. Thanks for the other explanation also.

Answer (score 1):

Pure list comprehensions solution:

```
[case [X||X=#rec{name=XN}<-M, XN=:=N] of [] -> Y; [#rec{value =V}|_] -> Y#rec{value=V} end || Y=#rec{name=N} <- L].
```

little bit more effective using `lists:keyfind/3`:

```
[case lists:keyfind(N,#rec.name,M) of false -> Y; #rec{value=V} -> Y#rec{value=V} end || Y=#rec{name=N} <- L].
```

even more effective for big M:

```
D = dict:from_list([{X#rec.name, X#rec.value} || X<-M]),
[case dict:find(N,D) of error -> Y; {ok,V} -> Y#rec{value=V} end || Y=#rec{name=N} <- L].
```

but for really big M this approach can be fastest:

```
merge_join(lists:keysort(#rec.name, L), lists:ukeysort(#rec.name, M)).

merge_join(L, []) -> L;
merge_join([], _) -> [];
merge_join([#rec{name=N}=Y|L], [#rec{name=N, value=V}|_]=M) -> [Y#rec{value=V}|merge_join(L,M)];
merge_join([#rec{name=NL}=Y|L], [#rec{name=NM}|_]=M) when NL<NM -> [Y|merge_join(L,M)];
merge_join(L, [_|M]) -> merge_join(L, M).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lists:ukeymerge/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#ukeymerge-3):

```
lists:ukeymerge(#rec.name, M, L).
```

Which:

> returns the sorted list formed by merging TupleList1 and TupleList2.
>   The merge is performed on the Nth element of each tuple. Both
>   TupleList1 and TupleList2 must be key-sorted without duplicates prior
>   to evaluating this function. When two tuples compare equal, the tuple
>   from TupleList1 is picked and the one from TupleList2 deleted.

A record is a tuple and you can use #rec.name to return the position of the key in a transparent way. Note that I reverted the lists L and M, since the function keeps the value from the first list.

Comment: I am not absolutely sure I understand your idea. The lists are not sorted in any way and I don't think I can sort them correctly, because `M` varies in size.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov: It is technique well known in database world as merge join. For big sets it is fastest technique even those sets are not sorted yet. If you have M values in lookup and N data using lookup up loop has O(N*logM) + O(M*logM) for building indexes. When using merge join you will get O(M+N) + (O(N*logN) + O(M*logM)) for sorting. But in some cases you can even sort in O(N) so you will got O(M+N) vs O(N*logM) which can be better for comparable big N and M.